# Extra data to kendo-ui query

Tags: c#, asp.net, reactjs, kendo-ui

I'm struggling with passing object through query method in kendo-ui on datasource (POST). When I'm initializing datasource, I'm able to send through property "data" some object, but I don't know how to do that, when I'm querying datasource.

```
let filterObject = {
    "Filter": "mydata"
};
this.dataSource.query({
    filter: filters,
    serverFiltering: //some props,
    serverPaging: //some props,
    pageSize: //some props,
    //data: filterObject,
    page: 1
})//more stuff here, irrelevant now
```

I know that when I'm using GET, it works fine with "filter" property(it's embedded in url), but with POST method I'm not receiving that on server side (and the additional object on server side is same, as initalizated). Please assume, that everything else is set up properly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you take a look into https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/configuration/transport.create#transportcreatedata?

Comment: Can't check that right now, but it seems, that using function as a data might work (data will be able to change when needed I guess). Tomorrow I'll update. Thank you for this suggestion (I was focusing more on a query method).

Comment: Can you show the signature of the controller method handling the read and a sample of the data object sent ?

Comment: Ups, forgot to update, my apologies. Function as a data worked perfectly, data were changing dynamically, so I really appreciate Carsten's suggestion.
The signature looked smth like (I don't have access right now, so I'm writing from memory):
    public CustomJson Post(ODataQueryOptions options, CustomClass filter)
and data I was sending was things, that goes usually in url (like "?name=&lastname=&$filter=id eq 10 or id eq 11"). With GET, the url sometimes were too long and app crashed, so I had to change that to POST, but without changing everything else. Thanks again!